# jquery hover tabs , bottom and top row, share central container

Tags: jquery, tabs, hover

Hope you well!

I've got a small project here to resolve...

…i've been playing and set up a jsfiddle here to illustrate the goal required…

…i've positioned tab elements top and bottom...top tabs are green, bottom tabs are red…

…the bottom row of tabs in red need to be a different CSS class as I need to apply a different graphic to those…

..i've had a fiddle but unsure of binding this to accommodate both "moving_bg" class for top row of tabs…and the "moving_bg-B" class for the bottom row.

…essentially the 8 UL blocks of content, need to share that central container:

http://jsfiddle.net/AMCBP/

…as we can see we have the correct html structure and css applied, however the UL blocks don't slide beyond UL block number 4 when using the bottom row of tabs.

...as a jquery noob any assistance, pointers very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was this :

```
   var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg");
```

You have written animation for only one class `.moving_bg` which is your top tabs so the anitmation was working perfectly. Your bottom tab has `.moving_bg-B` class, so no animation was placed for that class.

If you want to use the both Top and Bottom tabs animate together you need to use union of both classes.

```
 var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg,.moving_bg-B");
```

In the above code am doing an union of both the classes.

Update JSfiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/AMCBP/2/

Comment: ...thanks for reply, very much appreciated, your correct with the additional class "moving_bg-B"...

Comment: …problem i have is that the bottom row of tabs need to slide in the final four blocks as I have eight and not four…

Comment: …so, for example, at the moment "Title 5" tab at the bottom, just reveals the first content...when it needs to be showing the fifth block (as it is technically the fifth tab)

Comment: ...for example..."Title 5" tab when hovered reveals "Content 5" block, rather than "Content 1" block. "Title 8" tab would reveal "Content 8" block. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: …as we can see at the moment the UL blocks don't slide beyond UL block number 4 when using the bottom row of tabs.

Comment: ...if all the tabs are all at the top, it works, but the problem appears when the tabs are in another block of markup lower down > [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EV8wP/)

Comment: ...so i need to somehow mimic this, but with the tabs underneath instead: [ORIGINAL FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/AMCBP/2/)